# Custom Module - Use on Multiple Pages

Tags: module, ce-1.9.0.1

I am new to magento and have just starting creating custom modules. I have one which adds pagination to a custom collection.

Everything works for this. My declared `<frontName>custom-collection</frontName>` in `config.xml` means that the pagaination and collection show on `http://www.website.com/custom-collection`

But i also now have to add 2 other pages with slightly different collections (different filtered by etc...) to have pagination.

Is it possible to reuse this same module for however many pages i want or do i need to replicate this module for every page that wants a collection with pagination?

My module setup is:

```
Custom
    Collection
        Block
            Collection.php
            Toolbar.php
        controllers
            IndexController.php
        etc
            config.xml
        Helper
            Data.php
```

Files are:

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Collection>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Custom_Collection>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <collection>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Custom_Collection</module>
                    <frontName>custom-collection</frontName>
                </args>
            </collection>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <collection>
                    <file>collection.xml</file>
                </collection>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <collection>
                <class>Custom_Collection_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>collection_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </collection>
            <collection_mysql4>
                <class>Custom_Collection_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <collection>
                        <table>collection</table>
                    </collection>
                </entities>
            </collection_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <collection_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Collection</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </collection_setup>
            <collection_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </collection_write>
            <collection_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </collection_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <collection>
                <class>Custom_Collection_Block</class>
            </collection>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <collection>
                <class>Custom_Collection_Helper</class>
            </collection>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

`IndexController.php`

```
    class Custom_Collection_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();  

        $head = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); 
        $head->addItem('skin_js', 'js/grid.min.js');
        $head->setTitle('Custom Collection');
        $head->setDescription('.....');

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

`Collection.php`

```
<?php
class Custom_Collection_Block_Collection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        // filters...

        $this->setCollection($collection);

    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $parent_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id',false)){
            $parent_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
        }
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent_id);

        if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
            if ($title = $category->getMetaTitle()) {
                $headBlock->setTitle($title);
            }
            if ($description = $category->getMetaDescription()) {
                $headBlock->setDescription($description);
            }
            if ($keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords()) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
        }
        $this->setTitle($category->getName());

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'collection.pager')->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(9=>9, 12=>12, 18=>18, 36=>36, 'all'=>'all'));
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);

        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }
    public function getDefaultDirection(){
        return 'asc';
    }
    public function getAvailableOrders(){
        return array(
            'name'=> 'Name',
            'created_at'=>'Newest',
            'toprated'=>'Most Popular'
        );
    }
    public function getSortBy(){
        return 'name';
    }
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('collection/toolbar', microtime());
        return $block;
    }
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

`Toolbar.php`

```
    class Custom_Collection_Block_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar{
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        $pagerBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager');

        if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {

            /* @var $pagerBlock Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
            $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

            $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(true)
            ->setShowPerPage(true)
            ->setShowAmounts(true)
            ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
            ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
            ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            return $pagerBlock->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the router/urs for rest of  two

Comment: Sorry do you mean the urls (as in this is ../custom-collection/ ? It's 'product-collection' and 'unique-collection'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to so this by  custom url system

### my simple logic is

```
`custom-collection` internally goes to `modulename/controller/methodname/id/1/`
`product-collection` internally goes to `modulename/controller/methodname/id/2/`
`unique-collection` internally goes to `modulename/controller/methodname/id/3/`
```

Please  add below code inside the `config.xml` inside the `<global>` tag for trigger an observer  on `controller_front_init_routers`

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <vendor_module>
                <class>Custom_Collection_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </vendor_module>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

Then create the file `app/code/YourcodePool/Custom/Collection/Controller/Router.php` for **custom route checking**

```
<?php
class Custom_Collection_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('custom_collection', $this);
        return $this;
    }    
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        //split the urlKey by slash
        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
        //check if there are at least 3 parts (special, id and the actual id)
        //if there are less than 3 it means it's not the url you are looking for
        if (count($parts) < 3) {
            return false;
        }
        //check if every part matches what it should
        if ($parts[0] == 'custom-collection') {
            //get the id
            $id = '1';
            //TODO: add here additional check to see if $id is valid (if an entity with your id exists)
            //tell the request to map to your controller
            $request->setModuleName('module_front_key_here')
                    ->setControllerName('controller_name_here')
                    ->setActionName('action_name_here')
                    ->setParam('id', $id);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }elseif($parts[0] == 'product-collection'){
              $id = '2';
             $request->setModuleName('module_front_key_here')
                    ->setControllerName('controller_name_here')
                    ->setActionName('action_name_here')
                    ->setParam('id', $id);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;

        }elseif($parts[0] == '3'){
              $id = 'collection3';
             $request->setModuleName('module_front_key_here')
                    ->setControllerName('controller_name_here')
                    ->setActionName('action_name_here')
                    ->setParam('id', $id);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;


        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**then on id param  change** the collection at  `Custom_Collection_Block_Collection`

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')=1):
       $collection
    elseif($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')=2):
         $collection
    elseif($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')=3):
       $collection
    else:
    endif;
    ...
    // filters...

....
        $this->setCollection($collection);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer and explanation , great work!